# Fill NaNs in a column with the column max

Tags: python, pandas, nan

My data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2, np.nan, 2, np.nan],
                   'b':[np.nan, np.nan, 3, 3]})

a      b
2      np.nan
np.nan np.nan
2       3
np.nan  3
```

looking to get

```
a      b
2      3
2      3
2      3
2      3
```

Tried forwardfill

```
df = df.ffill()
a      b
2      np.nan
2      np.nan
2      3
2      3
```

Tried forward fill but because i had nan as the first row in `b`, i got nan still in `b`. How can i go about filling with unique values of each row instead? (the columns all have repeating values or np.nan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain a `bfill` call:

```
df.ffill().bfill()

     a    b
0  2.0  3.0
1  2.0  3.0
2  2.0  3.0
3  2.0  3.0
```

---

To allow pandas to downcast to `int`s if possible, use

```
df.ffill().bfill(downcast='infer')

   a  b
0  2  3
1  2  3
2  2  3
3  2  3
```

---

Another option is `fillna` with `max`.

```
df.fillna(df.max(), downcast='infer')

   a  b
0  2  3
1  2  3
2  2  3
3  2  3
```

`max` ignores NaNs, so is a good alternative.